# How would I go about making elements underneath a div visible?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have been trying to make a "hidden text" website of sorts.

I have managed to code a circular `div` that follows my mouse cursor and inverts every text underneath it using `background-filter` in CSS and Javascript:

```
let circle = document.getElementById('circle');

const onMouseMove = (e) => {
    circle.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    circle.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
}
  
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
```

The CSS for the #circle element is:

```
#circle {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px white;
    pointer-events: none;
    backdrop-filter: invert(100%); 
    z-index: 100;
}
```

I have tried setting the text opacity to 5% and then setting `backdrop-filter: opacity(100%)` but that didn't work, unfortunately.  How should I go about achieving this?  I am open to any and all libraries and willing to follow any tutorial.  Accessibility is not an issue at the moment as this is just an experiment for myself.

Comment: Please select a correct answer if your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make the effect you want using the [CSS `clip-path` property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip-path/):

```js
const content = document.getElementById("content");

const onMouseMove = (e) => {
  content.style.clipPath =
    `circle(40px at ${e.pageX}px ${e.pageY}px)`;
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis arcu diam, mattis vel mi sit amet, consequat dapibus sapien. Integer blandit et justo sit amet pharetra. Quisque facilisis placerat aliquet. Proin at dictum sapien. Proin ac urna quis leo
    vehicula semper. Pellentesque condimentum scelerisque aliquam. Nunc vitae pellentesque tortor.</p>
</div>


<div id="circle"></div>
```